# DB2.iSeries ConnectionString with Port

Tags: c#, db2, database-connection, connection-string, ibm-midrange

I am trying to connect to DB2 using the following connection string:

```
 <add name="ConnectionString" 
         providerName="IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries" 
         connectionString="Data Source=xxxxxxx,1234;UserID=username;Password=password;"/>
```

And it seems that if I specify the port (1234) it throws an error:

```
CWBCO1004 - Remote address could not be resolved
11001
A communication error occurred.
```

If I didn't specify the port it throws (expectedly):

```
Unhandled Exception: IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2ConnectionTimeoutException: The co
nnection cannot be opened because the connection timed out.
   at IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2Connection.Open()
```

Any way so that I can specify the port on the connection string and still works?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Typically the port number is separated from the host name by a semicolon (":"), not a comma (",")

Comment: @mustaccio Thank you for your reply. I tried that as well but throws the same error with ",". "CWBCO1004 - Remote address could not be resolved"
It seems that it's trying to resolve xxxxxxx:1234

Comment: Are you able to ping the host xxxxxxx ?

Comment: @DariusX. yup. ping and telnet xxxxxxx 1234 is fine.

Comment: I'm not familiar with .Net, but according to the DB2 documentation (http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.adonet.ref.doc/doc/DB2ConnectionClassConnectionStringProperty.html) there is no "Data Source" parameter in the ConnectionString property. There is a separate property DataSource though.

Comment: @mustaccio Thank you. But I am using IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries and the doc is for IBM.Data.DB2 and I believe they are different. If I use 'Server' it throws 'iDB2InvalidConnectionStringException'

Comment: OK, looking at the iSeries provider documentation, it doesn't appear to give an option to specify the TCP/IP port. I would presume then that it's either always the same, or is defined using the IBM iSeries Access software.

Comment: @mustaccio I think you are right. It might not be supported. Man the documentation is awful. Hard to find things. And it's IBM! <end rant/>

Comment: @mustaccio hi mate, put your answer as answer and I'll mark it as answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, looking at the iSeries provider documentation, it doesn't appear to give an option to specify the TCP/IP port. I would presume then that it's either always the same, or is defined using the IBM iSeries Access software.